# ExtJs Store.Load() vs Model.Load()

Tags: javascript, extjs

What is the difference between `store.load()` vs `model.load()`? One uses `callback`, the other uses `success/failure`, with slightly different function signatures.

Other than that, is there any main difference to use `store.load()`, OR not use it and just directly call `model.load()`? Difference when loading nested models with relationships?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at "Usage in Stores" section of [Ext.data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) documentation you'll find these two sentences:

> A Store is just a collection of Model instances - usually loaded from a server somewhere. Store can also maintain a set of added, updated and removed Model instances to be synchronized with the server via the Proxy.

and

> It is very common to want to load a set of Model instances to be displayed and manipulated in the UI

So this means that store is typically used as a collection (or I would call it a repository) of many model instances that syncs data with defined backhand and maintains a list of model instances that can be filtered, queried etc.

On the other hand `Ext.data.Model.load` method only loads one instance data by specific model id.

Based on this I would say that difference between `Ext.data.Model.load` and `Ext.data.Store.load` is in amount of data you want to load (one or many model instances).